# how to call a function from iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I have put an angular app inside an iframe, and I want to call his functions.

```
<iframe #iframe frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:4200/edit/username"></iframe>
```

http://localhost:4200/edit/username This link is a component of page-editor

```
export class PageEditorComponent implements OnInit...{
 @Input() eventMessage = { message: ''};

 handleEvent(eventMessage: { message: string; page: string }) {
    // if there are any possibility to put somethings in eventMessage 
    if (eventMessage.message.includes('tablette')) {
      this.loadIframe('tablette');
    }

  }
}
```

my aim is to call any function of PageEditorComponent from iframe

Comment: is your component getting loaded inside the iframe ?

Comment: Yes everything works fine

Comment: In that case the ngOnInit method should get fired as the component loads. Isn't that getting fired ?

Comment: yes, but I have a button save under iframe, my aim is when I click on this button I wanna save data, and function save is inside the iframe

Comment: yes. So you're trying to interact from inside the iframe to the outside. In such cases, the window object has methods that can be used to implement this event. When you hit save you post an event using the window.postMessage. and your other side of code would have to keep a watch on this. And then call the actual save method. Hope no confusion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the other way to look at this is using the Window.postMessage() APIs to communicate from within the iframe to outside. And your angular code would have to look for messages/events. It would be more like a message bus for communication between the two sides.